# Round number after .20

Tags: php, rounding

I'm trying to round up the number after 0.2 so for example if the number is 10.19 it should display 10 if 10.20 or above 11

I did read about the round function but I can't figure how to achieve the effect described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$rounded = ceil( $yournumber - 0.2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add 0.3:

```
rounded = round(original + 0.3)
```

That way, an original value of 10.2 will end up as 10.5, which will be rounded to 11.

Alternatively, you could add 0.8 and then use `floor`.

(This is all assuming positive values. If your numbers can be negative, you'll need to do a bit more work.)